# Assign output to variable for command run under different user on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I run a bash python command as current user, by doing this:

`su $USER -c 'python3 -m site --user-site'`

This works properly and prints the following:

`/Users/standarduser7/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages`

I want to assign this output to a variable, so I'm using `"$(command)"`:

`target="$(su $USER -c 'python3 -m site --user-site')"`

At this point, the OSX terminal hangs and has to be killed. Using backticks instead of `"$(command)"` leads to same result.

However, if I run the command without user, everything works as it should:

`target="$(python3 -m site --user-site)"
echo target`

output: `/Users/standarduser7/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages`

How can I assign the output from a command run as the current user to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s hanging; I think it’s showing a blank (prompt-less) command-line and is waiting for input.  When I key in the user password, it returns this result:

```
Password:/Users/CK/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

and this is what ends up being stored in the `target` variable.  A quick parameter substitution can rectify this anomalous output:

```
target=${target#*:}
```

The other solution (credit given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636741/9051006) answer) is to create a file descriptor as a copy of `stdout`, then `tee` the command to the copy, which then allows `stdout` to be piped to `grep` in order to process the output:

```
exec 3>&1 # create a copy of stdout

target=$(su $USER -c "python -m site --user-site" | tee /dev/fd/3 | grep -o '\/.*')

exec 3>&- # close copy
```