# Save bash script output to variable

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that, among other things, runs a command. For context, it's running a `unison` profile for file synchronisation.

The script takes parameters which are passed to the `unison` function, like so (shortened)

```
#!/bin/bash
unisonparameters=$1
unisonresult=$( { unison $unisonparameters local; } )
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    <<send email using $unisonresult>>
fi
```

I'd like to be able, to run the script in 2 ways:

1. as a cronjob, in which case I pass the parameters that require no user interaction (`-batch`), and the scripts emails me in case there is an issue.
2. as a user-initiated action, in which case I pass no parameters, so that `unison` asks me what I want to do with the files it found. In this case I'm indifferent to whether or not an email is sent.

I was hoping the script above would work, but as discussed in the comments it does not. Is there a way to make it work?

---

## Additional information 1

I've been trying to get the script to ask for user input if I pass no parameters (so that `$unisonparameters = ''`). Here are the results

**Working**

If dont try to save the output to a variable, like so:

```
unison $unisonparameters local
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    <<send email>>
fi
```

, all is run as expected and without error:

```
elrudi@dell:~$ ./syncnas.sh 
Mon Oct 22 22:23:17 CEST 2018
Syncing data with nas.
Found a local device at 192.168.1.100 to connect to.
running command 'unison local'...
Contacting server...
Connected [//nas//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi -> //dell//home/elrudi]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server                                       
Reconciling changes

local          nas           
new dir  ---->            syncAll/newFolder  
new file ---->            
(...)
```

(first lines due to other parts in script.)

**Broken**

However, if I use the original line in the script above, trying to store the output of this command:

```
unisonresult=$( { unison $unisonparameters local; } )
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    <<send email>>
fi
```

, it hangs on the `unison` command:

```
elrudi@dell:~$ ./syncnas.sh 
Mon Oct 22 22:01:17 CEST 2018
Syncing data with nas.
Found a local device at 192.168.1.100 to connect to.
running command 'unison local'...
Contacting server...
Connected [//nas//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi -> //dell//home/elrudi]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server                                       
Reconciling changes
Terminated!
```

(Last line caused by my eventual `ctrl-c`.)

---

## Additional information 2

I've tried adding `-debug verbose` to the `unison` command to get some more information. In both cases the output is very long. The interesting part is at the end, which i'm showing below.

**Working**

In the first case, with `unison $unisonparameters -debug verbose local` the script eventually asks for user input regarding which files to sync in which direction:

```
(...)

[server: update+] Archive name is //nas//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi;//nas//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi, //xps//home/elrudi;22; hashcode is 1cee08d0fa648cd9d77332dc9623b39e
[server: remote+] Sending result (id: 16)
[server: remote+] send [unlockArchive-res] '\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000...' 21 bytes
[server: remote+] send [rsp] '\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000...' 21 bytes
[server: remote_emit+] dump: \016\000\000\000\246\024\000\000\000\233rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@&\000\000\000\018unlockArchive-res\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@
[remote_emit+] grab: \016\000\000\000\246\024\000\000\000\233rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@&\000\000\000\018unlockArchive-res\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@
[remote+] Message received (id: 16)
[remote+] receive 'rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000...' 24 bytes
[remote+] receive 'unlockArch...' 38 bytes
[remote+] Waiting for next message

(...)

[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg' = false
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Qnap/3_Unison/syncnas.sh' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Qnap/3_Unison/syncnas.sh' = false
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/test4txt' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/test4txt' = false

local          nas           
new file ---->            syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Desktoppr/02126_snowytracks_2560x1600.jpg  
new file ---->            syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg  
changed  ---->            syncFolder/Software_Config/Qnap/3_Unison/syncnas.sh  
new file ---->            syncFolder/test2.txt  
new file ---->            syncFolder/test4txt  

Proceed with propagating updates? []
```

**Broken**

In the second case, with `unisonresult=$( { unison $unisonparameters -debug verbose local; } )` the script (i.e., the `unison` command) does not show the prompt:

```
(...)

[server: update+]   Unchanged file
[server: fileinfo+] /share/HDA_DATA/elrudi/syncFolder: true 1540240561.000000 1540240561.000000
[server: update] Setting archive for //nas//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi
[server: remote+] Sending result (id: 9)
[server: remote+] send [find-res] '\132\149\166\190\000\000\000/\000\000...' 67 bytes
[server: remote+] send [rsp] '\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000...' 21 bytes
[remote_emit+] grab: \t\000\000\000b\024\000\000\000\233rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@K\000\000\000\181find-res\132\149\166\190\000\000\000/\000\000\000\000\000\000\000 \000\000\000\029\160\176'syncFolder@\160\224\160\001\001\255\001\003\255@@\145\012\000\000\128  \223\214A@\018_j\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@@
[remote+] Message received (id: 9)
[server: remote_emit+] dump: \t\000\000\000b\024\000\000\000\233rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@K\000\000\000\181find-res\132\149\166\190\000\000\000/\000\000\000\000\000\000\000 \000\000\000\029\160\176'syncFolder@\160\224\160\001\001\255\001\003\255@@\145\012\000\000\128  \223\214A@\018_j\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@@
[remote+] receive 'rsp\132\149\166\190\000\000\000...' 24 bytes
[remote+] receive 'find-res\132\149...' 75 bytes
[remote+] Waiting for next message
Reconciling changes
[recon] reconcileAll
[recon] reconcile: 3 results
[update] Marking 0 paths equal
[pred] sortlast 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg' = false
[pred] sortlast 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[pred] sortfirst 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg' = false
[pred] sortfirst 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[sort] syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg <= syncFolder/test.txt --> -1
[pred] sortlast 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[pred] sortlast 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
[pred] sortfirst 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[pred] sortfirst 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
[sort] syncFolder/test.txt <= syncFolder/test2.txt --> -1
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/Software_Config/Linux/variety/Downloaded/Unsplash/photo-1535941863447-76a4dc94e2ba.jpg' = false
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/test.txt' = false
[pred] forcepartial 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
[pred] preferpartial 'syncFolder/test2.txt' = false
```

(hangs on last line)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I doubt this should matter, but `unisonresult=$( unison local )` should be sufficient; the command group is unnecessary.

Comment: I would have tried `unison local > /tmp/unison$$.out 2>&1` to capture both stdout and stderr to the file.  Then use that file, and remove it...
But I don't know why your solution is hanging... :-(

Comment: Do you have a `while` loop in `syncnas.sh` that looks at a variable set by `unison`? When `unison` runs in a subshell, variables set by `unison` ae lost after terminating that shell.

Comment: Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365228/57293, you can try `{ unison local  > /dev/fd/3 2>&1; x=$(cat<&3); } 3<<< ''; echo "${x}"`. The drawback of this solution is that you only see the output of `unison` when the command is finished. When this resolves the `hanging` problem, the solution might be using `tee` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636741/3220113

Comment: If `unison` is trying to interact with your TTY, well, there you are. Redirecting stdin `</dev/null` is a good way to stop that from happening, if "stopping that from happening" is appropriate.

Comment: BTW, while they aren't hurting anything either, the curly braces don't add anything useful here -- you'd have exactly the same behavior from `unisonresult=$(unison -debug verbose local)`