# Split intermediate pipe to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Consider the following **toy** example (what I'm really doing is more complicated) where I want to get two pieces of information from the same sequence of commands:

```
echo 'cats pajamas
hatori hanso
batterang
catwoman
fratstar' > tmp1

answer1=$(grep 'cat' tmp1)
answer2=$(grep 'cat' tmp1 | wc -l)
```

In essence, I'm looking for a way to only need to run the earlier command(s) in the sequence, in this case `grep`, once, while still obtaining *exactly* the same values stored in variables `answer1` and `answer2`.  I imagine this would work as splitting the pipe (so to speak) to `answer1` and to `wc -l`, with the output of the latter going to `answer2`.

Note that using an intermittent variable or file to store the output of `grep` would alter what `wc -l` returns.  This motivates my choice of this toy example and limits the relevance of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99440/pipe-assigns-variable#99443), I think.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636665/pipe-bash-command-output-to-stdout-and-to-variable) appears related, however it's not clear to me how one would assign the intermediate piece to another variable.  I'm currently in `bash`, though alternate shells are an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tee` with a pair of named pipes. (Strictly speaking, you could do this with one pipe and the standard output of `grep` itself, but the presentation is simpler with two pipes.)

```
mkfifo p1 p2
grep cat tmp1 | tee p1 p2 > /dev/null &
answer1=$(cat p1)
answer2=$(wc -l < p2)
```

`tee` splits the output just as you want, writing it to two separate pipes which are read from independently by `cat` and `wc -l` later.

I assume this is more applicable to your use case than `answer1=$(grep 'cat' tmp1)` and `answer2=$(echo "$answer1" | wc -l)`.

Comment: This appears to hang at the `answer1=...` line, even though it seems `p1` should've been open for reading and writing at that point...if I add an `&` to the end of that line, it completes, however `answer1` appears empty.  Investigating...

Comment: I've resolved it, and it's working as expected, thanks.  I think something was still holding onto the fifo.  So as to put a bow on it, can you revise your answer to clean up `p1` and `p2`?